# Numbers $e^{iz}$, where $\Re(z) \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: complex-numbers

What part of complex plane are numbers $e^{iz}$, where $\Re(z) \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$? Can you help? I've been trying to figure that out for quite a long time and still don't know...

Comment: Start by writing $z=x+iy$ and mucking about with $e^{iz}$. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Ok, so I have numbers $e^{ix-y}$ where $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. How does it help me?

Comment: Can you put $e^{ix-y}$ in polar form?

Comment: Oh, is it going to be the whole first quadrant?

Comment: Can you write it as a set $\{a+bi \mid \cdots\}$?

Comment: $\{a+bi | a>0, b>0 \}$

Comment: Yep. You got it.